# How to consume RabbitMQ messages via pika for some limited time?

Tags: python, python-2.7, rabbitmq, pika

All the examples in pika tutorial end with the client invoking `start_consuming()`, which starts an infinite loop. These examples work for me.

However, I do not want my client to run forever. Instead, I need my client to consume messages for some time, such as 15 minutes, then stop.

How do I accomplish that?

Comment: The answer of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180596/set-timeout-for-pika-ioloop-async-rabbitmq/8181008) may be useful.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can consume messages one at a time with your own loops, say you have a `channel` and `queue` setup. The following will check if the queue is empty, and if not, pop a single message off of it.

```
queue_state = channel.queue_declare(queue, durable=True, passive=True)
queue_empty = queue_state.method.message_count == 0
```

declaring a queue that already exists, and setting the passive flags allows you to query it's state. Next we process a message:

```
if not queue_empty:
    method, properties, body = channel.basic_get(queue, no_ack=True)
    callback_func(channel, method, properties, body)
```

Here `callback_func` is our normal callback. Make sure **not** to register the callback with the queue when you want to process this way.

```
# DO NOT
channel.basic_consume(callback_func, queue, no_ack=True)
```

This will make the manual consume do weird things. I have seen the queue_declare code actually process a message if I have made this call beforehand.

Comment: Presumably I need invoke channel.close(), so that the exit is clean, right? Is there anything else I need to do on exit?

Comment: Also I guess I could just invoke this:  method, properties, body = channel.basic_get(queue, no_ack=True), followed by if not body is None. Can you explain why do you recommend checking if queue is empty first?

Comment: Yes, you should close the channel. I check the queue this way because it is more clear what is going on, you could for instance, wait until you have N messages on the queue before processing. The `None` check is fine too though.

Comment: @Mike I am trying to use RabbitMQ on my localhost, but having hard time with it, can you give me any pointers regarding that